# How to read negative binary data using BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Int32)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a binary data file and it contains some negative and positive value also and it stored in 2's complement form.
Whenever I try to read those data using `BinaryReader` class I am always getting positive number.

```
 private double nextByte(BinaryReader reader)
        {
            byte[] bValue = reader.ReadBytes(2);
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(bValue.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in bValue)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            int decValue = int.Parse(hex.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            return Convert.ToDouble(decValue);
        }
```

For Example:
Let's consider data file contains `1011100101011110`. Equivalent Decimal value is 47454, and Decimal value of signed 2's complement is -18082.
The `BinaryReader.ReadBytes(2)` methods will always returns +ve value but I am excepting -18082 value.

The problem is data file contains both +ve and -ve value, So how can I achieve this please any one can help me.

Comment: `BinaryReader.ReadBytes(2)` returns an array of bytes. How you interpret these bytes is up to you. You are not showing the code that does the interpretation.

Comment: If the data is a short, why not use `BinaryReader.ReadInt16`?

Comment: That code is all over the place. The method is called `nextByte()`, but it's clearly reading multiple bytes. And it's unclear why you're returning the value as a `double`. Can you explain why you're not returning a `short` or `int`?

Comment: An int 32 is 4 bytes but you are only reading two bytes.

Comment: @jdweng `Int32` is the argument type from the [method signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes?view=netcore-3.1), not the intended result type.

Comment: I am storing this data in double array, yes it can be store in short also but array has some big and real numbers also.

Comment: Read Title of posting!!!

Comment: A double is 8 bytes, not 4 bytes.  Single is 4 bytes.

Comment: @jdweng I was specifically talking about the title of the posting. The `Int32` in the title is the argument type from the [method signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes?view=netcore-3.1), not the intended result type.

Comment: @Nitish You are reading two bytes, converting each to its unsigned hex representation, concatenating them, parsing the result as an int and converting that to double. It would make no sense even if you actually wanted to produce `short`s as the outcome (which consume 2 bytes), not `double`s (which require 8). If your binary stream contains actual binary representations of `double`s, then remove all that code and call [`reader.ReadDouble`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readdouble?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: I would just use the method @harold mentioned. It's going to be *much* more straight forward than reading a byte array, converting that to a string, parsing it as an int, and finally converting that to a double.

Comment: See wiki for doubled format : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue with your crazy conversions you simply need to cast resulting `int` to `short`:

```
 int decValue = 47454;
         // int.Parse(hex.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
 return (short)decValue;
```

The cast to `short` will simply trim 2 high bytes of `int` resulting in representation of negative value, and then resulting `short` value `-18082` will be automatically converted to `-18082.0f` to match return type.

Note that reading `short` directly with [ReadInt16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readint16?view=netcore-3.1) is likely what you want.